Dual edge triggered Bistable Multivibrator
Design a bistable multivibrator to increase the frequency at which the data is stored. When doing so, ensure that the data is stored at the rising and falling edge of the clock. However, due to lack of resources, only MUxes are available to implement this.
How many MUXes will be needed to achieve this objective?
Well, I thought of implementing this using a dual edge detector circuit but it requires a XOR gate so it will take up a lot of MUX.and the design is to be done within 2-5 MUX.PLease help me with this.

aditya arya - Hi, Judging by the way it is written, I guess that in the 1st paragraph you are repeating the assignment which has been given to you. Is that correct? If so, please use blockquotes as that is the site standard here, for when someone is quoting text. Also make it clear where this is coming from e.g. add "My original college assignment is" or whatever is the correct explanation. If the assignment is coming from a book, then follow the site referencing rule. In short: Please be clear who each piece of text belongs to. TY

It isn't clear what "stored" means, but assuming "bistable multivibrator" is just a fancy name for "flip-flop" (i.e., latch), it only takes one mux to make a latch, and you'll need one latch for each edge of the clock. A third latch will be required if you want to time-align the outputs.

Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, it is not a forum. Please read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. -- Additionally to the other requests for clarification: If you already have ideas, please add them by [edit]ing your question and tell us why you stumble with them.

You are misled by the requirement for edges, I suppose for purpose. ;-) Another option are level sensitive latches.
First, let's look how latches are built by muxes. The following schematic shows both kinds of latches, positive level sensitive (MUX1) and negative level sensitive (MUX2).

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
MUX1 is transparent when EN is high, its output follows the input. If EN is low, MUX holds the last state of the input before the falling edge and ignores any further changes.
MUX2 works the same but with inverted levels on its EN.
Now we need to combine these two in a way that the combined output forwards only the held and therefore stable values. For this we need a third mux.

simulate this circuit
A table might help in understanding.



CLK
output MUX1
output MUX2
output MUX3




low
stable
follows input
forwards MUX1 (stable)


high
follows input
stable
forwards MUX2 (stable)



Of course, there are setup and hold times to consider.
So, the answer to the embedded (homework) question is three muxes.
